# dimension of singular set of torsion free sheaves over a unit disc

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose $D\subset\mathbb C$ is a unit disc and $\mathcal F$ is a torsion free analytic coherent sheaf over $D$.  Define $S(\mathcal F)=\{x\in D|\mathcal F_{x}\, is \,not\, locally\, free\}$.  Is $S(\mathcal F)$ always empty?  I know there is a theorem in Friedman's book algebraic surfaces and holomorphic vector bundles shows that if the base is algebraic, $S(\mathcal F)$ is always codimension two.  Is it still true if the base is analytic but not algebraic?

Comment: Yes. A finitely generated, torsion-free module over a discrete valuation ring  is free.

Comment: But here only the germ at  a fixed point is a ring, how do we apply your results?

Comment: A basis of $\mathcal{F}_x$ as an $\mathcal{O}_x$-module gives a basis of $\mathcal{F}$ in a neighborhood of $x$.